# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to Google Cloud MySQL from Google App engine but getting OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

I've tried using following settings:

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python37
env: standard

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

db connection string: `mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{db}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{conn_name}`

My concern is it was working before but when I changed the db user/password it started giving me above error and reverting my last change did not solved my problem. Is there some issue with my settings or could it be some cache issue on app engine?

Comment: This is likely due to a [recent outage](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/19003), can you still reproduce this?

Comment: Yes still getting the same error @DustinIngram

Comment: Can you try to connect to your MySQL instance using SQLAlchemy engine [1] ? [1]: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#connecting_the_standard_environment_to

Comment: Or try to use connection string like: mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@/{db}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{conn_name}, since you are trying to connect from App Engine, not from external source.

Comment: @Jaroslav thanks the link worked, I had to manually construct the connection string using sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL() method instead of using above mentioned string.

Comment: @WaqasJaved No problem, I will publish it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to connect to your Google Cloud SQL instance from App Engine standard environment you can find in Google documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#connecting_the_standard_environment_to).